# Casual ways to ask meaning?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, colloquial-language

I know 〜はどう言う意味ですか？ but how might you ask this question in a casual setting among friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phrase like this can be asked a lot of ways, in a casual tone.

Simplest I think would be:

> ｘｘって何｛なに｝？

This can be used both for meaning and also identification of objects.

If you want to be specific about asking for a meaning, I'd try:

> ｘｘの意味｛いみ｝は何｛なに｝？

Or, say, something with two possible meanings, I'd go with:

> ｘｘって、何｛なん｝の意味｛いみ｝？

or

> ｘｘって、どんな意味？

Comment: thank you! this is a perfect answer :))